# Magento 2 - UI Component WYSIWYG field not saving

Tags: magento2, xml, uicomponent, cms-pages

I am trying to add some fields to CMS pages so I can add some stuff to the sidebar. 
I followed some tutorials I found online but seem to be missing something.

The current setup correctly shows the fields but when I change the default text in the magento backend the changes to the text are not saved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="sidebar_content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sidebar Content</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="sidebar_element">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zijbalk blok 1</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">detail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">this is the default text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="sidebar_element_2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zijbalk blok 2</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">detail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">this is the default text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="sidebar_element_3">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zijbalk blok 3</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">detail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">this is the default text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there something else I need to add, like do I have to update the save functionality, because I didn't read about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the data_scope apparently, I simplified it and it now works as expected:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="sidebar_content">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sidebar Content</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <field name="sidebar_element" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Header Titel</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="sidebar_element_2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zijbalk blok 2</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">sidebar_element_2</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="sidebar_element_3">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zijbalk blok 3</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">sidebar_element_3</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```